# Organising data and code across modules in Prolog

Tags: module, prolog

I'm developing a simple web service which is going to add user provided facts to my Prolog database (using `assert`). I thought it's better to keep these dynamic facts ("data") separate from my service rules that operate on these facts ("code"), hence split them into two different modules. Main reason was that I wanted to persist the dynamic facts to disk periodically, while being able to develop the code with no issues and independently of user data.
I've been using `assert(my_store:fact(...))` to add user data to the `my_store` module and then in the code module I started coding rules like

```
:- module (my_code, [a_rule/1, ...]).

a_rule(Term) :-
   my_store:fact(...), ...
```

All seems ok but with this approach `my_store` is hard-coded in the code module, which is a little worrying. For example, what if after some time I decide to change data module name or, perhaps, I'll need two separate data modules one with frequent persistence, another with persistence done only sporadically?

Can anyone advise what are the best practices in code and data organisation? Perhaps separation of code and data is against "the Prolog way"? Are there any good books that cover these issues in depth?

Cheers,
  Jacek

Answer (score 3):

That's a good question, touching on several very important topics.

I hope that the following comments help you to sort out most of your questions, possibly more so if you follow up on the points that interest you most with new questions that address the specific question in isolation.

1. First, when accepting user code as input, make sure you only allow **safe code** to be added to your programs. In SWI-Prolog, there is `safe_goal/1`, which helps you to ensure some safety properties. It's not perfect, but better than nothing.
2. Again in SWI-Prolog, there is [**library(persistency)**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=persistency). Please carefully study the documentation to see how it works, and how you can use it to store dynamic data on disk.
3. Regarding the module names, I have two comments:

   - *Explicit* module qualifications of goals are very rare. Simply load the module and use its clauses.
   - Note that you can load modules *dynamically*. That is, nothing prevents you from using `use_module/1` with a parameter that was obtained from somewhere else. This allows you more flexibility to specify the module from which you want to fetch your definitions, without having to change and recompile your code.

Regarding separation of code and data: In Prolog, there is no such separation.

All Prolog clauses **are** Prolog terms.

### Terms! TERMS ALL THE WAY DOWN!

Comment: Thx for the hints. (1) The service is not supposed to accept the raw code but will create facts out of requests sent by users. Yet, good to know about `safe_goal`, I wasn't aware of it; might be useful in the future. (2) I came across the `persistency` library, haven't got time to look it up yet but it's on my reading list. (3) I'm not sure I follow that suggestion. If facts are created dynamically by user HTTP requests and stored in the data module, how I can load that module? Do I need to refresh it every time I run the code? Or perhaps directive `use_module(my_store)` does all the magic?

Comment: All the way down? That's turtles, I wot.

Comment: @Jacek: You load a module with `use_module/1`, for example: `update_from(Module) :- use_module(Module).`, where `update_from/1` can be invoked after the `Module` is available. Alternatively, simply make the HTTP server run `make/0` to update all definitions as new ones become available. Please ask a separate question if you would like to have more information about a particular aspect of this. It is too long for a comment.

Comment: Just because a distinction between code and data doesn't exist in the **solution** domain, it doesn't mean that it doesn't exist in the **problem** domain as a (possibly) key concept that may need to be represented as accurately as possible.

Comment: @mat: The trouble with `use_module` is that it operates on files, whereas my module is created dynamically when user data arrive. I'm going to propose a solution in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @mat for his suggestions which made me to read and think a little more. Now, I can post a potential solution to my issue; not ideal, not using the [`persistency`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=persistency) library but a simple, first attempt.

As mentioned, user data are stored with `assert(my_store:fact(...))`. That means module `my_store` is created dynamically and there's no file which would allow `use_module` to be used. There's, however, the [`import/1`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=altmoduleapi) predicate which I can use to import dynamically asserted facts, and so my solution looks like this:

```
:- module(my_code, [a_rule/1, ...]).

:- initialization import_my_store.

import_my_store :-
   import(my_store:fact/1),
   import(my_store:another_fact/1),
   ...

a_rule(Term) :-
   fact(...), ...
```

Note that I can use `fact/1` without explicit specification of the `my_store` module. And I can also easily dump the user data to a file.

```
save_db(File) :-
   tell(File),
   my_store:listing,
   told.
```

The downside is that on initialization the `import/1` calls generate warnings such as: `import/1: my_store:fact/1 is not exported (still imported into my_code)`. But that's not a big issue because they are *still imported into my_code* and I can use the user facts without explicit module specification.

Looking forward to hearing any comments. Cheers,

Comment: Why don't you simply use `include/1` to include all definitions from a file?

Comment: Because initially, there's no file which would represent the `my_store` module. I'd like to keep it like that, if possible, because it gives me more leeway in the number of data modules I may have.

Comment: You can simply test whether the file exists, and use `include/1` only if the file exists: `( exists_file(F) -> include(F) ; true)`.

Comment: Ok, but how would it help if there's no module file yet, users added some data and I want to use the data without explicit module specification?

Comment: `include/1` makes the clauses of a different file usable *as if they appeared in the same file*, so you do not need a module specification. Note that the use of such constructs resembles logic *hacking* more than logic programming. I still recommend to use either `library(persistency)`, or your own module files and `use_module/1`. The predicates that the module exports are all usable *without* explicit module prefix! Also look into the `multifile/1` directive: It seems applicable in your use case.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using Logtalk, which provides an alternative to modules. First define an object with your code:

```
:- object(my_code).

    :- public([a_rule/1, ...]).

    :- private([fact/1, another_fact/1, ...]).
    :- dynamic([fact/1, another_fact/1, ...]).

    a_rule(Term) :-
        ::fact(...), ...

    ...

:- end_object.
```

Then, dynamically create any number of data stores as necessary as extensions (derived prototypes) of the `my_code` object:

```
?- create_object(my_store, [extends(my_code)], [], []).
```

To query a data store, simply send it a message:

```
?- my_store::a_rule(Term).
```

The `create_object/4` built-in predicate can load the persistency file for the store if necessary (so that you resume where you left):

```
?- create_object(my_store, [extends(my_code)], [include('my_store.pl'))], []).
```

User data can by saved in a data store by asserting it as expected:

```
?- my_store::assertz(fact(...)).
```

You will need a predicate to dump a data store to a file as a public predicate in the `my_code` object. For example:

```
:- public(dump/0).
dump :-
    self(Self),
    atom_concat(Self, '.pl', File),
    tell(File),
    dump_dynamic_predicates,
    told.

dump_dynamic_predicates :-
    current_predicate(Functor/Arity),
    functor(Template, Functor, Arity),
    predicate_property(Template, (dynamic)),
    ::Template,
    write_canonical(Template), write('.\n'),
    fail.
dump_dynamic_predicates.
```

now you can dump a data store, by typing:

```
?- my_store::dump.
```

Note that with this solution is trivial to have concurrently any number of data stores. If a data store requires a specialized version of the code, then you can simply extend the code object and then create the specialized data store as an extension of that specialized object.

Comment: Thanks Paulo for an alternative solution. Currently, I'm working more with SWI-Prolog but will keep the Logtalk approach in my mind.

Comment: SWI-Prolog is one of the supported Prolog systems (you can also use the solution above also with other 11 Prolog systems). Note that this is a solution that you can use *with* and *from* SWI-Prolog, not a *either* SWI-Prolog or Logtalk solution scenario.